# Wait for one animation to finish before starting another

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation

I have a mouseenter animation on a footer and also a mouse leave animation that just slides it abit, the issue im having is if you mouse enter then mouseleave multiple times quickly the animations que and run over and over even if the element is no longer beign used.

How do I wait for the mouse over to run before it then recognises the mouse leave please.

Many thansk for any help

David

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("footer").mouseenter(function () {
    $("footer").animate({ bottom: '+=62px' }, 500);
});


$("footer").mouseleave(function () {
    $("footer").animate({ bottom: '-=62px' }, 500);

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `stop()` to your `animate` functions. It stops the currently-running animation on the selected element.

```
$("footer").mouseenter(function () {
  $("footer").stop().animate({ bottom: '+=62px' }, 500);
});

$("footer").mouseleave(function () {
  $("footer").stop().animate({ bottom: '-=62px' }, 500);
});
```

Comment: @David_George Please accept the answer if it worked.